# CakePHP How to override already declared model validation error messages?

Tags: validation, cakephp, model-view-controller

I can successfully put new messages in view files only if they are not present in model. I mean validations have to be in model, but messages attached to those validations should not be there.

Example model

```
public $validate = array(
        'username' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'required' => true, 'allowEmpty' => false,
                'message' => 'Please enter a username.'),
            'alpha' => array(
                'rule' => array('alphaNumeric'),
                'message' => 'The username must be alphanumeric.'),
            'unique_username' => array(
                'rule'=>array('isUnique', 'username'),
                'message' => 'This username is already in use.'),
            'username_min' => array(
                'rule' => array('minLength', '3'),
                'message' => 'The username must have at least 3 characters.')),
        'email' => array(
            ...................
            ...................
```

and here's an example of view

```
echo $this->Form->input('username',array(
            'label' => __d('app_users','Username'),
            'error' => array(
                'required' => __d('app_users', 'Please enter a username'),
                .....................
                .....................
        ));
```

So, my question is how can one make it into a work without removing `'message' => 'Please enter a username.'` in a model but to TRULY OVERRIDE IT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I mean validations have to be in model, but messages attached to those validations should not be there.

And how do you then have messages for a JSON API service? The text contained in validation has nothing to do with how your site looks so should not be in a view.

You can change the validation message from the model or from custom validation methods without much hassle and its all in the [book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#dynamically-change-validation-rules)

Comment: I cannot change validation messages from outside model if they are existing in model already. If `message` key exists in model validation then they cannot be overridden. JSON API? What if you don't specify a message there; type of validation is being returned.

Comment: I'm extending a plugin and I don't want to remove validations there, nor rewrite whole validation variable into my AppXXX

Comment: You can, I linked already how to do it. All you need to do is RTFM. `$ModelInstance->validator()->getField('password')->getRule('required')->message = 'This field cannot be left blank';`

Comment: everything is possible that way. I wanted it in my views from `$this->Form` helper. anyways I will copy plugin code to my extended model and get around that way. thanks.